# How to change method that pass couple value to field in state?

Tags: reactjs

I have field `numberCoupleIdDelete` in state:

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState({
    numberCoupleIdDelete: [],             
  });
```

When I click `input` near item with `id` number 3:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick={() => props.deleteСoupleСategory(item.id)}/>
```

I pass `id` item with number `3` to field `numberCoupleIdDelete` using method `deleteСoupleСategory`:

```
const deleteСoupleСategory = (argDeleteCategory) => {
    setValue({
        ...value,
        numberCoupleIdDelete: [argDeleteCategory]
    });
};
```

in `state` I have:

`numberCoupleIdDelete: [3]`

Then I click near item with id number `7`. And I should can state like this:

`numberCoupleIdDelete: [3, 7]`

**But instead I have:**

`numberCoupleIdDelete: [7]`

#### That is, my method instead of adding a new array element rewrite value current array.

How to change method that pass couple value to field `numberCoupleIdDelete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, just use array deconstructing with the spread operator:

```
const deleteСoupleСategory = (argDeleteCategory) => {
    setValue({
        ...value,
        numberCoupleIdDelete: [...value.numberCoupleIdDelete, argDeleteCategory]
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I still want to ask you something. Now when I will remove checkmark from item with id 3 instead this:
`numberCoupleIdDelete: [3]` I have: `numberCoupleIdDelete: [3, 7, 3]` 
How to fix it?

Comment: @nion if you want to remove an element from the array numberCoupleIdDelete you can use:
`setMyState((prevState) => {
      return {...prevState, numberCoupleIdDelete: prevState.numberCoupleIdDelete.filter((x) => x != id)}
    })` where id is the element you want to filter